# ECS Scheduled Task Start and End Time

Tags: python, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, aws-event-bridge

How do i get the start and end time of an ECS scheduled task using CLI or SDK?

```
aws events describe-rule
```

only provides basic information with no start and end time.

Comment: What's the output? It should include the EventPattern or ScheduleExpression.

Comment: I'm trying to work out the duration of the scheduled task and stop a task that has run over 36 hours.

Answer (score 0):

Answering based on further information provided in the comments.

If you're looking for the actual running tasks, you'll want to use the ECS [`list-tasks`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/list-tasks.html) and [`describe-tasks`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/describe-tasks.html). EventBridge just triggers jobs, it knows nothing about what's actually running.

Comment: Thanks but list-tasks and describe-tasks do not appear to list scheduled ecs tasks but just the standard ecs tasks.

Comment: @manoman687 Based on your comment above I don't understand what you're looking for. How can a task be scheduled (not running) but also have run for over 36 hours?

Comment: We want to kill long running scheduled tasks if it is running over a certain amount of time. Sometimes these tasks appear to run longer than the anticipated length of time.

Comment: You’re misunderstanding what EventBridge does. You provide a schedule and it initiates tasks. There are no “scheduled” tasks and “standard tasks.” The APIs I provided you will allow you to list current tasks and determine which ones have been running for longer than expected.